# Dynamic text fields in pages with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, content-management-system

I would like your help/tip regarding an issue that comes often most of my projects

For example I would like to create a website with a bunch of pages and also create some text fields on different positions on a page (some on the top of the page and some on other positions). The case is that I would like those text fields to be dynamic (ability to store, edit, show, delete on the database) but I dont know what will be the schema of my Page migration so whenever I would like to echo the text field value i.e $page->field1, $page->field2

I suppose that the below is not the proper way to define the fields on my migration so I would like to assist me which is the best one!

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('field1');
        $table->string('field2');
        $table->string('field3');
        $table->string('field4');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: We use a dedicated model HelpText to handle such things. Example:  {{ HelpText::get('splash.some_message') }} will render a translated text. But also, if logged in as admin, we will render a little edit button/link to allow edits

Answer (score 1):

I once did the following the achieve the same.
Create a new model for your content on the page. I called it content.
`php artisan make:model Content -m`

In the migration you add your required properties and create a relationship to your Page model.

```
    Schema::create('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('page_id')->references('id')->on('pages');
        $table->string('body'); // the actual text
        $table->integer('page_position');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

You can use the 'page_position' table to render the info of the object at a certain location in your blade view, as simple example.

On your Page model you create the method to access the Content models that belong to the page.

```
class Page extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the content models related to this page.
     */
    public function contents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Content');
    }
}
```

Then you can access all related contents by calling the relationship

```
 foreach($page->contents as $content){
      $text = $content->body;
 }
```

Be sure to read [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships)